# Removing single entries from x-axis ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to figure out how remove specific values from the x-axis in my plot

```
df <- data.frame(schoolid = c(101, 102, 103, 104, "Mean"), 
value = c(2.5, 2, 4.3, 1, 3.5),
col = c("1","2","2","2","3" ))

 schoolid value col
1      101   2.5   1
2      102   2.0   2
3      103   4.3   2
4      104   1.0   2
5     Mean   3.5   3

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(schoolid, value), y = value, fill = col)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00","#999999",  "#56B4E9")) +
  ylim(0,5) +
  ylab("Value") +
  xlab(" ")
```

This gives me the (almost perfect) plot:
[image]

I want to remove all values from the x-axis that are labeled with 2 in df$col, while keeping the respective bars at the same time. My goal is to only have "101" and "Mean" shown on the x-axis.

I am struggling with the configuration of the x-axis, because "zooming" removes the bars I want to keep.I also tried to simply remove the values from the df and filling them with " ", but then the plot can not be created correctly.

> UPDATE:  With the brain-kickstart from Leonardo in the comments I
> figured out a way to do it.
>
> 1. add a column to the dataframe that contains the names of the labels for the plot.
> 2. order the dataframe in the way the bars should be ordered in the plot.
> 3. use scale_x_discrete(labels = x), where x is the labels from the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(schoolid = c(101, 102, 103, 104, "Mean"), value = c(2.5, 2, 4.3, 1, 3.5), col = c("1","2","2","2","3" ), label = c("101", " ", " ", " ", "Mean"))
    df <- df[with(df, order(value)),]
    ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(schoolid, value), y = value, fill = col)) +
              geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
              theme_minimal() +
              scale_x_discrete(labels=  df$label) +
              scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00","#999999",  "#56B4E9")) +
              ylim(0,5) +
              ylab("Value") +
              theme(legend.position = "none") +
              xlab(" ")
```

This is resulting in the correct plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hardcoded, but it does the trick:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(schoolid, value), y = value, fill = col)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c(" ", " ", "101", "Mean", " ")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00","#999999",  "#56B4E9")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ylim(0,5) +
  ylab("Value") +
  xlab(" ") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that gave me a good start to figure out a non-hardcoded version!